# Why is meteor adding ObjectId around the _id field since today?

Tags: meteor

Maybe I'm completely wrong, but since projects that I start today, when I use meteor mongo to connect directly to the mongodb, and insert a record (with mycol.insert(..) the _id field is surrounded with ObjectId("12345555...").
When adding a record from code this is not the case.
So, records added via Meteor Mongo are not recognised inside the app any longer.
I have done this in the past so often...
what's happening here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's the MONGO way and you see this because you are using the Mongo shell. Meteor defaults to a different method (cf below) which you see when you use it programmatically. Check Meteor docs on `new Mongo.Collection`

**idGeneration** String

The method of generating the _id fields of new documents in this collection. Possible values:

- 'STRING': random strings
- 'MONGO': random Mongo.ObjectID values

The default id generation technique is 'STRING'

In Meteor, if you write

```
Steffo = new Meteor.Collection("steffo", {idGeneration: 'STRING'});
```

this will result in entries

```
{ "foo" : "bar", "_id" : "68FWFNGRAuRt82pWy" }
```

If you use

```
Paul = new Meteor.Collection("paul", {idGeneration: 'MONGO'});
```

you'll get

```
{ "foo" : "bar", "_id" : ObjectId("26cfdb5f200adfa0b55a50d3" }
```

The latter happens when you use Mongo shell.

Comment: I see but my point is that i have projects where the mongo shell generates strings. Recent projects use object id.

Comment: Do mean that you insert docs into the same collection from within Mongo shell and from within the code? You can have a collection with ObjectId and another one with Meteor RND Strings within the same project. You just have to handle the _id differently. I don't see an issue here.

Comment: My point is that meteor mongo seems to behave differently between meteor projects. Sometimes it uses string for the id, sometimes objectID when doing an insert. When doing an insert from code, always string is used.

Comment: Show me how you create the collection in Meteor, please.

Comment: from meteor mongo I do:
db.customers.insert({"firstName": "john","lastName":"Doe"})

Comment: What I meant is: how do CREATE the collection. In Meteor, if you write `Steffo = new Meteor.Collection("steffo", {idGeneration: 'STRING'});` this will result in entries `{ "foo" : "bar", "_id" : "68FWFNGRAuRt82pWy" }`. If you use `{idGeneration: 'MONGO'}` this results in entries with `"_id" : ObjectId("26cfdb5f200adfa0b55a50d3")`. (Updated answer cause its not easy to read in the comment)