# How to let pathFor create the URL path based on this.params._id?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Can't make clickleable links for the individual projects:

**router.js:**

```
Router.route('/projects/:_id', {
  name: 'projectPage',
  template: 'projectPage',
  data: function() {
    return Projects.findOne({ _id: this.params._id })
  }
})
```

**project_list.html:**

```
<template name="projectList">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="page-header">My Lessons</h2>
      {{#each projects}}
        {{> project}}
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**project.html:**

```
<template name="project">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="thumb-1.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p><a href="{{pathFor 'projectPage'}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Check out</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**project_page.html:**

```
<template name="projectPage">
  <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="row">
      <h2 class="page-header">{{title}}</h2>
      <h2 class="page-header">{{description}}</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I get this weird URL: `http://localhost:3000/projects/ObjectID(%22566b810371d07711cf9d6680%22)`

And I'm taken to `projectPage` but nothing shows at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that iron router is seeing an `ObjectID` in your item's `_id` where it expects to find a `String`. You could use the following instead, converting your ObjectID into a String on-the-fly:

**project.html:**

```
<template name="project">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="thumb-1.png" alt="...">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>{{title}}</h3>
        <p>{{description}}</p>
        <p><a href="{{pathFor 'projectPage' _id=this._id.toHexString}}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Check out</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

But then you will have to convert it back to an ObjectID in your route:

**router.js:**

```
Router.route('/projects/:_id', {
  name: 'projectPage',
  template: 'projectPage',
  data: function() {
    return Projects.findOne({ _id: new Meteor.Collection.ObjectID(this.params._id) })
  }
})
```

Comment: @SyvainB. Worked, thanks! No idea why the Meteor Development Group complicated something that used to be so simple. The code is twice as long now. (Still loving Meteor, though.)

Comment: To my knowledge, the use of `String` as an ID has not changed in latest meteor... You are likely inserting these documents in an "unusual" way. (through the mongo shell, through a specific package...) See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27402289/1439597)

Comment: Oh, I did it with `meteor mongo` and `db.project.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });` So that's the reason? If I insert them normally with a form from within the app, I'd get strings as before?

Comment: Normally, yes! So make sure your route and pathfor are behaving the expected way for one or each case!